# How to observe individual input elements which were created in bulk in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a set of `sliderInput`s whose number equals the number of columns in my data. The number of columns is determined by the values of `choices` from `global.R`. Each slider is associate to one column and were created as shown bellow in `server.R` and `ui.R`.

I would like to `observe` them individually so I can apply the values to the associated column. Something like in this example. 
Any suggestion?

```
 #Example. Not valide code!!!
 selectedValBySliders <- observe({ 
    print("Numbers selected via sliders:") 
    out_sliders <- input$sliders[1:numSliders]
    print(out_sliders)
  })
```

#### server.R

```
    output$sliders <- renderUI({
      numSliders <- numCols(input$dataName)
      lapply(1:numSliders, function(i) {
        sliderInput(
                    inputId = paste0('column', i),
                    label = paste0('Select the range for column ', i),
                    min = min(selectRange(input$dataName)),
                    max = max(selectRange(input$dataName)),
                    value = c(min(selectRange(input$dataName)), max(selectRange(input$dataName))),
                    step =1)
        })
    })
```

#### ui.R

```
            uiOutput(outputId = "sliders"),
```

#### global.R

```
 selectRange <- function(x){
  if(x == "data1"){choices = c(1:10)}
  if(x == "data2"){choices = c(1:15)}
  if(x == "data3"){choices = c(1:20)}
  if(x == "data4"){choices = c(1:25)}
return(choices)  
}

 numCols <- function(x){
  if(x == "data1"){ncolumns = 4}
  if(x == "data2"){ncolumns = 5}
  if(x == "data3"){ncolumns = 5}
  if(x == "data4"){ncolumns = 6}
return(ncolumns)  
}
```

Comment: Can you indicate what is your numCols function ? Thank you !
Adrien

Comment: `numCols` is a function which return the number of columns for each data. You can simulate the data with `data_k <- t(combn(n, k))`. In my case `n = 10, 15, 20, 25` and `k = 4, 5, 5, 6`.  I edited the question with `numCols`.

Comment: Click here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827829/how-to-select-rows-of-a-matrix-which-has-to-meet-mutiple-conditions-in-r-shiny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone might bump into the same issue, here is my solution.
Feel free to update it with a better answer if you have one.

```
  minMax <- matrix(0, ncol(getData), 2)
  for(i in seq(ncol(getData))){
    if(!is.null(input[[paste0('column', i)]])){
    val <- input[[paste0('column', i)]]
    minMax[i,] <- val
    index <- which(getData[, i] %in% c(minMax[i, 1]:minMax[i, 2]))
    selectedSet <- getData[index, ]
  }
}
```