# How to select rows of a matrix which has to meet mutiple conditions in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The goal is to build an application able to select and present only rows of a matrix that meets specific conditions selected by the user via Shiny elements such as `checkboxes` and `sliderInput`
Our `data` is subject to two (or more) ways to be filtered:

1. Via `checkboxGroupInput` where user can select one or more numbers
2. Via `sliders`. There will be one slider for each column of `data`. This allows user to select the range of numbers for each column.

I got stuck on making the `data` react to the selection entered by the user. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Here is the code that I have:

#### server.R

```
   # Load libraries.
   library(shiny)
   library(datasets)
   library(xtable)
   library(R.utils)

 shinyServer(
     function(input, output) {
      source('global.R', local=TRUE)

getDataName <- reactive({
  out <- input$dataName
  print(out)
  return(out)
})

getData <- reactive({
    cat("Getting data for, ", getDataName(), ".", sep = '')
  if(getDataName() == ""){
      print("ERROR: getDAtaName is empty! Check your code!")
      out <- NULL
  }
  else {
      dataSet <- t(combn(max(selectRange(getDataName())), numCols(getDataName())))

  }
  print(head(dataSet, n = 10))
  return(dataSet)
})


selectedValues <- reactive({
  print("Numbers selected via checkboxes:")
  print(input$numSelector)
})      

output$numSelector <- renderUI({
  out <- checkboxGroupInput(
    inputId = "numSelector",
    label   = "Select the numbers to be included in the rows",
    choices = selectRange(input$dataName),  
    inline = TRUE
  )
  return(out)
})

output$sliders <- renderUI({
  numSliders <- numCols(input$dataName)
  lapply(1:numSliders, function(i) {
    sliderInput(
      inputId = paste0('column', i),
      label = paste0('Select the range for column ', i),
      min = min(selectRange(input$dataName)),
      max = max(selectRange(input$dataName)),
      value = c(min(selectRange(input$dataName)), max(selectRange(input$dataName))),
      step =1)
  })
})



output$selectedDataDisplay <- renderDataTable({
  as.table(getData())}, options = list(lengthMenu = c(5, 30, 50), pageLength = 10))
}
```

)

#### ui.R

```
library(shiny)

 shinyUI(
    pageWithSidebar(
       headerPanel("Selection zone"),

# Select inputs
sidebarPanel(

  selectInput(
    inputId = "dataName",
    label   = "Select data",
    choices = c("data1", "data2", "data3", "data4")
  ),


  uiOutput(outputId = "numSelector"),
  uiOutput(outputId = "sliders")

),

mainPanel(
   tableOutput("selectedDataDisplay"))

 )
)
```

#### global.R

```
 selectRange <- function(x){
 if(x == "data1"){choices = c(1:10)}
 if(x == "data2"){choices = c(1:15)}
 if(x == "data3"){choices = c(1:20)}
 if(x == "data4"){choices = c(1:25)}
 return(choices)
}

numCols <- function(x){
 if(x == "data1"){maxNum = 10
               numCol = 5}
 if(x == "data2"){maxNum = 15
               numCol = 5}
 if(x == "data3"){maxNum = 20 
              numCol = 5}
 if(x == "data4"){maxNum = 25 
              numCol = 6}
 return(numCol)
 }
```

Comment: can you identify `selectRange`? It is a user defined function or from a package?

Comment: I think it's better if you post a reproducible example

Comment: I edited the question. Basically, `data` can be different. Instead 20 it might 40 or something else. I have all this defined in a `global.R` and they are sourced according to the name of the data selected by the user.

Comment: This question intrigued me because of the logistics, but it is not making sense to me any more, maybe I am not understanding on this point: If you specify different ranges for different columns, are you wanting all rows that satisfy at least one criterion or only the rows that satisfy ALL the criteria?

Comment: @mkemp6: I posted all the files needed for this question. Question has been edited to be in sync with the added code. I cannot display the table, for some reason and don't want to make you wait until I will fix it.

Comment: @mkemp6: To answer your question, I want all the rows that satisfy ALL the criteria. For example, if I select number 13 in the `checkboxGroupInput`, it should show all rows that has 13. Then, if I select the range from one of the sliders (which corresponds to one of the columns) it should show rows which has that specific column with values in the range selected by that slider. And so on...

Comment: So if you specify for column one to only show rows with values 5-10 but then specify column 2 to show rows with values 5-10, but that includes rows in column one that are not within 5-10, you would like to show those rows too?

Comment: @mkemp6: Yes. This will work for cases with overlap, where , for example, column one is c(1:7) and column two is c(5:10) .

Answer (score 2):

You did not provide your actual data sets, so I simulated a couple, and I don't have your exact formulas but hopefully you can extend the idea:

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Selection zone"),

    # Select inputs
    sidebarPanel(

      # User enters name of dat.frame here.
      selectInput(
        inputId = "dataName",
        label   = "Select your data",
        choices = c("data1", "data2", "data3", "data4")
      ),


      uiOutput(outputId = "numSelector"),
      uiOutput(outputId = "sliders")

    ),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Model Summary", dataTableOutput("selectedDataDisplay"), textOutput("vars"))

      )
    )
  ))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

data1 <- matrix(round(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 20), 0), ncol = 10)
data2 <- matrix(round(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 20), 0), ncol = 10)
data3 <- matrix(round(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 20), 0), ncol = 10)
data4 <- matrix(round(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 20), 0), ncol = 10)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$numSelector <- renderUI({
    out <- checkboxGroupInput(
      inputId = "numSelector",
      label   = "Select the numbers to be included in the rows",
      choices = 1:20,  
      inline = TRUE
    )
    return(out)
  })


  output$sliders <- renderUI({
    numSliders <- eval(parse(text = c("ncol(",input$dataName, ")")))
    lapply(1:numSliders, function(i) {
      sliderInput(
        inputId = paste0('column', i),
        label = paste0('Select the range for column ', i),
        min = 1,
        max = 20,
        value = c(1, 20),
        step = 1)
    })
  })

  dataSet <- reactive({
    if ( is.null(input$column1) ){

    } else {
      colName <- "Column"
      eval(parse(text = c(paste0("set <- as.data.table(", input$dataName, ")"))))
      setnames(set, colnames(set), paste0(colName, seq(ncol(set))))

      # generate boolean values for each column's rows based upon individual ranges & the over all 
      validRows <- list()
      for(k in seq(ncol(set))){
        validRows[[k]] <- eval(parse(text = paste0("with(set, ", colName, k, " %in% input$column", k, "[1]:input$column", k, "[2] &  ", colName, k, " %in% input$numSelector )")))
      }

      validRows <- do.call(cbind, validRows)

      # if any of the column's conditions are satisfied, the row is accepted
      validRows <- apply(validRows, 1, any)

      # ouput accepted rows
      set[ validRows ]  
    }
  })

  output$selectedDataDisplay <- renderDataTable(dataSet(), options = list(lengthMenu = c(5, 30, 50), pageLength = 10))

})
```

Comment: The data is generated by `combn` function. I updated the question to generated the data in case you want to try it out. There were few things that were missing but now it should be fine. I will try your code and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't implemented it 100% just like that but it was my main source of inspiration. And, yes, it worked in the end! Thank you for following up! You deserve the points..:)